# GraphQL resolvers contained within a node process rather than a server?

Tags: node.js, graphql

I need to create something similar to a GraphQL server but fully contained within a node process rather than an actual server. So essentially a JavaScript function which you would call with a query or mutation as a string, and it would return an object or string with the response based on your resolvers.

It’s a weird requirement I know. We need to mock a GraphQL server at my company and due to some limitations in our build pipeline we can’t run an actual server.

Apologies that this quite an open question but I don't know where to start. What package contains the core functionality for GraphQL? If I was making a GraphQL server I'd use Apollo Server or GraphQL Yoga package, but it's hard to Google what I need as it's such an unusual requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need the vanilla GraphQL.js package (`graphql`) to execute a query against a schema. The package exports a `graphql` function with the following signature:

```
graphql(
  schema: GraphQLSchema,
  requestString: string,
  rootValue?: ?any,
  contextValue?: ?any,
  variableValues?: ?{[key: string]: any},
  operationName?: ?string
): Promise<GraphQLResult>
```

From the docs:

> The graphql function lexes, parses, validates and executes a GraphQL request. It requires a schema and a requestString. Optional arguments include a rootValue, which will get passed as the root value to the executor, a contextValue, which will get passed to all resolve functions, variableValues, which will get passed to the executor to provide values for any variables in requestString, and operationName, which allows the caller to specify which operation in requestString will be run, in cases where requestString contains multiple top-level operations.

So given a schema, you can just do:

```
const request = `
  query MyQuery {
    someField
  }
`
const { data, errors } = graphql(schema, request)
```

Note: If you have `typeDefs` and `resolvers` that you'd normally pass to an ApolloServer config, you can create a `GraphQLSchema` object by passing them to `graphql-tools`' `makeExecutableSchema` instead (which is what `apollo-server` and `graphql-yoga` use under the hood).